# How to get the user current country phone code ex:+966

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see many apps correctly guess my correct country code +966,+962 ...

I am trying to get that prefix of the country phone code but all examples are use the **NSLocal** which give me a wrong result.

ex: my local is United stat so when i get the country phone code it give me +1
but when i open app like path it give me my country code correct +962

any idea how to get this?

Comment: use [HMDiallingCode](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMDiallingCode)

Comment: This library depend on location so it will ask the user to get the location permission which is not happened in apps like "Path"

Comment: You need users location to determine the country and country code. You sure that apps like Path not determine that from users profile or wifi etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Please download the following link for country code.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/1c2b972438c88480b23bdb44c0469bc56010d470/CountryCodes.json.
Save the json file and parse it accordingly